# not able to open image generated by ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to get images from the video stream using ffmpeg in python and I need the raw bytes to do further things. I am trying to store the raw bytes in image file so if my file opens then I can confirm that the raw bytes I have got are correct.

```
import subprocess as sp

def getImages(self):
  cmd = ['ffmpeg',
           '-ss', 2,
           '-i', url,
           '-t', 2,
           '-f', 'image2pipe',
           '-s', '420x360',
           '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-vf', 'fps=fps=1', '-']
  pipe = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
  raw = pipe.stdout.read(420*360)
  file = open('image.jpg','wb')
  file.write(raw)
```

I see a file image.jpg but I cannot open it. Is there anything wrong I am doing here? I am sizing the image to be 420*360 bytes so I am assuming that the first 420*360 bytes are belong to the first frame.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a 420x360 image with rgb24 pixels, every pixel takes up 3 bytes. Try `pipe.stdout.read(420*360*3)`.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn’t work.

Comment: Why are you saving as JPG? Your reader may be trying to parse it as one.